# How to add headerview to recyclerview with staggeredGridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, staggeredgridlayout

I want add a headerview like listview into recyclerview with staggeredGridLayoutManager. I have search all library and only found this one [RecyclerHeaderView](https://github.com/blipinsk/RecyclerViewHeader) but this library have limitation for LinearLayoutManager or GridLayoutManager. Is possible to add headerview for staggeredGridLayout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [setFullSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams.html#setFullSpan(boolean)) in the layout manager to create a row that looks like a header

```
public final void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) viewHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
}
```

Comment: how to implement that? should i change my adapter too?

Comment: i use onBinViewHolder to fill content of each reyclerview item, what the purpose create layoutParams in there?

Comment: I dont understand the question, you dont create anything in there you set the span to full width anytime you want to create a row that is a header

Comment: life saver! `layoutParams.setFullSpan( true );` works like charm