# How to put main cell on the top of StaggeredGridLayout(recycler view)?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I use `StaggeredGridLayout` in my `Recycler View`

What I need :

[image]

I can divide recycler view to 2 columns, but I don't know how to put main cell on top of the recycler view

I am not sure, but maybe I can put it in container and try to hide it during scrolling? Like we do with toolbar when user start to scroll toolbar gone up.

But I am not sure about it

How to put main cell on the top of StaggeredGridLayout(recycler view) ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, you want a **header**. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871947/how-to-add-headerview-to-recyclerview-with-staggeredgridlayoutmanager) helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these lines in onBindViewHolder method

```
if(position == 0){
      StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams =  (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
      layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually there is my adapter maybe will help someone to understand how does it work

```
public class AdapterRecViewMain
    extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private List<BaseMarkerElement> mainCardList;
private final int HEADER_VIEW = 0;
private final int FOOTER_VIEW = 1;

public AdapterRecViewMain() {
}

public void setData(List<BaseMarkerElement> mainCardList) {
    this.mainCardList = mainCardList;
}

@Override public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return HEADER_VIEW;
    }
    return FOOTER_VIEW;
}

@Override public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int type) {
    if (type == FOOTER_VIEW) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_main_activity, viewGroup, false);
        return new MainCardViewHolder(v);
    } else {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.header_view_main_activity, viewGroup, false);
        return new HeaderViewHolder(v);
    }
}

@Override public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int positionItem) {
    final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

    if (viewHolder instanceof HeaderViewHolder) {
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) viewHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);

        BaseMarkerElement item = mainCardList.get(position);
        if (item instanceof HeaderView) {
            HeaderView header = (HeaderView) mainCardList.get(position);
            // need to add implementation
        }
    } else if (viewHolder instanceof MainCardViewHolder) {
        MainCardViewHolder currentView = (MainCardViewHolder) viewHolder;
        CardMainActivity currentCard = (CardMainActivity) mainCardList.get(position);

        currentView.ivMainCard.setImageResource(currentCard.getIvMainCard());
        currentView.tvBrandName.setText(currentCard.getTvBrandName());
        currentView.tvPrice.setText(currentCard.getTvPrice());
        currentView.tvType.setText(currentCard.getTvType());
    }
}

@Override public int getItemCount() {
    return mainCardList.size();
}

private class MainCardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView ivMainCard;
    TextView tvBrandName;
    TextView tvType;
    TextView tvPrice;

    MainCardViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        ivMainCard = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewMainCard);
        tvBrandName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvBrandName);
        tvType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvType);
        tvPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
    }
}

private class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public HeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

    }
}
}
```